# Where are ASP.NET roles saved?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to use ASP.NET MVC roles. I added an entry in the web.config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\resorg-db.mdf;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
  </system.web>
```

I don't have migrations enabled, for now I prefer to have the DB recreated at every model change.

I programaticaly add a role in DB Initialize method, like:

```
Roles.CreateRole("root");
Roles.AddUserToRole(testUser.UserName, "root");
context.SaveChanges();
```

The problem:
When I run this the first time, all was fine. When I change the model and run the initialization method again, I get an error that the role already exists.
I looked through the database using Server explorer, but both AspNetRoles and AspNetUserRoles are empty.
Where are the roles saved? In the same folder with my DB there is another db, called aspnetdb.mdf.

I tried to open it using SysTools MDF Viewer 1.0, but I got invalid format.

Bonus question: I also have some tests in a different project. This one recreates the DB and run same tests. My problem is that I got this error:

```
System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException: The Role Manager feature has not been enabled.
```

although I added the same entry in my app.config for the unittest project.

Comment: it's defiantly in `AspNetRoles`, try to refresh the table content, you said that you have 2 DB's created, did you create one of them yourself?

Comment: Found the problem: I need to add the connection string to the roleManager entry. If there's no connection string, ASP.net will create a different DB to store the role. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911738/asp-net-membership-roles-saved-on-different-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem: I need to add the connection string to the roleManager entry. If there's no connection string, ASP.net will create a different DB to store the role. See [ASP.Net Membership: Roles saved on Different Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911738/asp-net-membership-roles-saved-on-different-database)